# How do I extract a string that spans multiple lines with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to extract the string between `CAKE_FROSTING("` and `",`. If the string extends over multiple lines, the quotation marks and newline at the line changes must be removed. I have a command (thanks stackoverflow) that does something in that direction, but not exactly. How can I fix it (and can you shortly explain the fixes)? I am using Linux bash.

```
sed -En ':a;N;s/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?\s*?"([^,]*).*/\1/p;ba' filesToCheck/* > result.txt
```

filesToCheck/file.h

```
something
CAKE_FROSTING(
"is supreme", 
"[i][agree]") something else
something more
something else
CAKE_FROSTING(
"is."kinda" neat"
"in fact", 
"[i][agree]") something else
something more
```

result.txt current

```
is supreme"
is."kinda" neat"
```

result.txt desired

```
is supreme
is."kinda" neat in fact
```

Edit: With help from @D_action I now have

```
sed -En ':a;N;s/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?\s*?"([^,]*).*,/\1/p;ba' filesToCheck/* > result.txt
```

this produces almost the correct output, but there are unnecessary quotation marks and one too many newline in the output:

result.txt current

```
is supreme" 
is."kinda" neat"
"in fact"
```

Comment: @anubhava I would be interested in the sed solution because it is the only one I know at least a tiny little bit about, but if another solution is better/easier/faster, then this is welcome.

Comment: you need to add a comma to say that your match must stop at comma. `*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?\s*?"([^,]*).*,`

Comment: Thank you @D_action, this helps, I added my remaining problem to the post in an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -En ':a;N;s/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n?\s"([^"]*[^\n,]*)["].*\n"([[:alpha:] ]+)?.*/\1 \2/p;ba' input_file
is supreme
is."kinda" neat in fact
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^CAKE_FROSTING($/!d;z;:a;N;s/^"\([^[].*\)".*/\1/mg;ta;s/^.\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;y/\n/ /' file
```

Focus on those lines that contain `CAKE_FROSTING(` and delete all others.

Having established the starting point, zap that line and then gather up following lines until one beginning `"[`, trimming the lines as we go.

Remove the initial newline and the unwanted last line.

Then replace any remaining newlines with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `perl` here to match string between `CAKE_FROSTING(` and `)` and remove double quotes from start/end of lines and replace linebreaks with spaces only inside the matches:

```bash
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/CAKE_FROSTING\(\s*"([^,]*)"/g) {$a=$1; $a =~ s/^"|"$|(\R+)/$1?" ":""/gme; print "$a\n"}' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/gKKkBB). Note that `-0777` slurps the file so that the regex engine could "see" the line breaks.

The `CAKE_FROSTING\(\s*"([^,]*)"` pattern matches `CAKE_FROSTING(`, zero or more whitespaces, `"`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more non-comma chars until the right-most `"`.

The `$a=$1; $a =~ s/^"|"$|(\R+)/$1?" ":""/gme; print "$a\n"` parts assigns the Group 1 value to an `$a` variable, `^"|"$|(\R+)` matches `"`s that are either at the start of end of lines or captures one or more line breaks (`\R+`) into Group 1 and if Group 1 matches, the replacement is a space, else, it is an empty string. The contents of the `$a` variable is printed only.