# How do I use "match a single character not present in the set" correctly in sed in linux bash?

Tags: bash, sed

Thanks to help from stackoverflow, I arrived at the command below. But `"match a single character not present in the set"` does not work as I expect. The first capture `([^"][^\n,]*)`should stop at `",` or `"\n` , but currently only stops at `",\n` . What is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Solution can only be in sed on linux bash and ideally is as close to my current command as possible (to be easier for me to understand).

```
sed -En ':a;N;s/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n*?\s*?"([^"][^\n,]*)"[\n,]?\s*"?(([^"][^\n,]*)?")?.*,/\1\3/p;ba' filesToCheck/*
```

file.h

```
something else
CAKE_FROSTING(
   "is supreme "
"and best", 
"[i][agree]") something else
something more
something else

CAKE_FROSTING(
"is."kinda" neat " "in "fact"", 
 "[i][agree]") something else
something more

something else
CAKE_FROSTING("is supreme", "[i][agree]") something else
something more
something else
```

current output

```
is supreme and best 
is."kinda" neat " "in "fact" 
is supreme "[i][agree]") something else
```

desired output

```
is supreme and best 
is."kinda" neat " "in "fact" 
is supreme
```

Comment: I think [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74345998/3832970) already [works for this string](https://ideone.com/8EjWvb), too, doesn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the solution, it probably does work for both, but I must confess I am already fully occupied with just understanding sed, and adding Perl into the mix would make the mess in my head complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -En ':a;N;s/.*CAKE_FROSTING\(\n*?\s*?"([^"][^\n,]*)"[\n,]?\s*"?(([^"][^\n,]*)?")?.*,[^\n]*/\1\3/p;ba' input_file
is supreme and best
is."kinda" neat " "in "fact"
is supreme
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, it is just a matter of matching any chars (as few as possible) until either `"\n` or `",`:

```bash
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/CAKE_FROSTING\(\s*"(.*?)"[\n,]/gs) {$a=$1; $a =~ s/^"|"$|(\R+)/$1?" ":""/gme; print "$a\n"}' file
```

From the previous solution, it differs in the `(.*?)"[\n,]` part that now captures

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible (`s` flag is added to make `.` match any chars including line break chars)
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[\n,]` - a newline or comma.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/MNy7zv):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='something else
CAKE_FROSTING(
   "is supreme "
"and best", 
"[i][agree]") something else
something more
something else

CAKE_FROSTING(
"is."kinda" neat " "in "fact"", 
 "[i][agree]") something else
something more

something else
CAKE_FROSTING("is supreme", "[i][agree]") something else
something more
something else'
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/CAKE_FROSTING\(\s*"(.*?)"[\n,]/gs) {$a=$1; $a =~ s/^"|"$|(\R+)/$1?" ":""/gme; print "$a\n"}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
is supreme 
is."kinda" neat " "in "fact
is supreme
```